# Null hypothesis in Cox regression with a conflict between confidence intervals and P-values

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, cox-model

Apologise for the simple question, I would just like to sanity check the interpretation of two results before I discuss them with a group of biologists.

I have two results from Cox regression:

Sample A: 0.9 (0.8, 1.2) **p=0.12**

and

Sample B: 0.9 (0.8, 1.2) **p=0.04**

How is one to interpret a result where the confidence intervals fall either side of the null-hypothesis in the situation where p isn't significant and then the situation where the p is significant?

Is it correct to say that one cannot interpret anything from Sample A whilst Sample B is significantly indifferent to the null?

Thank you

Comment: In most cases, if the 95%-CI does not include the null, then the corresponding $p$-value testing the null is $\leq 0.05$. So B is clearly an inconsistency and probably an error. In few cases, the most powerful test method and the best method for calculating a confidence interval use different approximations or different sampling distributions, so they would not yield the identical answer in every instance. But I'm not aware of such inconsistencies in Cox regression. Can you show the output of the software?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm away from my work machine at the moment so I don't have the output to hand. I would then be correct in saying that Sample A is statistically similar to the null?

Comment: Are the numbers in the parentheses the confidence interval? If so, it looks like your coefficient falls outside of your confidence interval. Could you double check that this isn't a typo?

Comment: No I wouldn't phrase it that way. I'd say that your sample is compatible at the 95% level with a hazard ratio ranging anywhere from 0.8 to 1.2. Because the null value of 1 (assumed) is among the compatible values, you have little evidence suggesting that the true hazard ratio is different from 1.

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo. Corrected.

Comment: I've added a real example Sample A.

Comment: That real example does not seem to have the problem you describe.